# Iodoform on acetone gives one product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

During the Iodoform reaction of acetone why does the second iodine addition happen on the carbon that already has undergone substitution instead of the other carbon?

Comment: There are _no both_. As soon as your first group succumbs to iodine and falls off as iodoform, you no longer have acetone, so why would the other group react?

Comment: I think a better way to frame the OP's question is to ask: why does the second iodine addition happen on the carbon that already has undergone substitution instead of the other carbon?

Comment: @ Ivan Neretin it does not form iodoform at once . According to the mechanism halogenation happens step by step. Meaning that alpha hydrogens are replaced one by one by halogen atoms